# How to change the animation effect of the wizard?

Tags: jquery

I have done a simple Wizard Script **jQuery** works perfectly.

Now my question is?

How can I change the animation to hide the data to this animation [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mvf1zu9t/) type tabs?

```
    $(".next").click(function() {
       //store parent
       var parent = $(this).parent();
        if(parent.next().length) {
           parent.hide("slow").next().show("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
    $(".prev").click(function() {
       var parent = $(this).parent();
        if(parent.prev().length) {
           parent.hide("slow").prev().show("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
```

**My complete code:** https://jsfiddle.net/jwzjys8u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use **fade** instead

```
 $(".next").click(function() {
   //store parent
   var parent = $(this).parent();
    if(parent.next().length) {
       parent.fadeOut("slow", function(){
            parent.next().fadeIn("slow");
       });
    }
    return false;
});
$(".prev").click(function() {
   var parent = $(this).parent();
    if(parent.prev().length) {
       parent.fadeOut("slow", function(){
            parent.prev().fadeIn("slow");
       });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Anyway you could use CSS to make transitions!

Comment: The effect is very close to what is desired.

Comment: It does not work when the buttons (previous and next) are inside a div tag as can be solved without deleting the div tag https://jsfiddle.net/Lkwanexe/

Comment: Yes it's possible to change the selector to match the buttons even if they're in a div. Do you want me to make the adjustment?

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers ;)