# How to animate the process Wizard with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have done a simple Wizard Script jQuery works perfectly while continuing with the data, I would like to be able to add the effect of the process.

Example this image:

[image]

> How can I animate the process of the shopping cart
>    image to continue with the process `step-1` animation `item1` of the process and so on?

```
 $(".button.next").click(function() {
   //store parent
   var step = $(this).parents(".step");
   if (step.next().length) {
     step.fadeOut("slow", function() {
       step.next().fadeIn("slow");
     });
   }
   return false;
 });
 $(".button.prev").click(function() {
   var step = $(this).parents(".step");
   if (step.prev().length) {
     step.fadeOut("slow", function() {
       step.prev().fadeIn("slow");
     });
   }
   return false;
 });
```

**Complete code:** https://jsfiddle.net/Lkwanexe/1/

> Thanks to the help of [Tony Samperi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749079/how-to-change-the-animation-effect-of-the-wizard)

Comment: What is your problem? We don't make homeworks.

Answer (score 0):

This is idea how to do that using jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

**1)** You need know step width between steps, so I make own map step|width

```
var lineStepWidth = {
  1: 120,
  2: 300,
  3: 450
};
```

Add HTML5 atribute data to define step

```
<div class="step step-1" data-step="1">
```

It can be also done with some css classes.

**2)** Make own simply function which will do animate

```
$.fn.animateLine = function(step) {
    var lineWidth = lineStepWidth[step]; // get step width from attribute and map
    $('#line').animate({
      width: lineWidth
    }, 1000);
};
```

**3)** Add own animate function to your actions

```
$.fn.animateLine(step.prev().data('step')); // step.next / step.prev
```

Thats it.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkwanexe/2/)

This is my idea for your next thinking about your problem.